# add data to listview from another activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-application-class

I'm really confused on how to add from another activity I keep getting an error in this part of the code:

```
Emails a = new Emails(intent.getStringExtra("inputEmail"), intent.getStringExtra("inputBody"), intent.getStringExtra("inputSubject"));
```

So the error says "actual and formal argument lists differ in length". if anyone could help me out it would be such a huge help thank you :)

this my code:

main activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button newEmail;
    private ListView listView;
    private EmailAdapter emailAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Emails> emailsArrayList;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();


         emailAdapter = new EmailAdapter(this, emailsArrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(emailAdapter);
         updateList();


        newEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void init(){
        newEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        emailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        Emails emails = new Emails ();
        emails.setEmails("josemari@yahey.com");
        emails.setSubject("Sample Data");
        emails.setBody("this is the sample data");
        emailsArrayList.add(emails);


    }

    private void updateList()
    {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(bundle != null)
        {
            Emails a = new Emails(intent.getStringExtra("inputEmail"), intent.getStringExtra("inputBody"), intent.getStringExtra("inputSubject"));
            emailAdapter.add(a);
            emailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Emails a = new Emails(intent.getStringExtra("inputEmail"), intent.getStringExtra("inputBody"), intent.getStringExtra("inputSubject"));
            emailAdapter.add(a);
            emailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         Log.d("MainActivity","onStart invoked");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("MainActivity","onResume invoked");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        Log.d("MainActivity","onPause invoked");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {

        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

this is the add item activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button send;
    private Button discard;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText subject;
    private EditText body;
    private ArrayList<Emails> emailsArrayList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        discard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discardBtn);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSubject);
        body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBody);


        discard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SendActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputEmail = email.getText().toString();
                String inputSubject = subject.getText().toString();
                String inputBody = body.getText().toString();

                if (inputBody.isEmpty() || inputEmail.isEmpty() || inputEmail.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(SendActivity.this, "Please enter the following data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    emailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    Emails newEmails = new Emails ();
                    newEmails.setEmails(inputEmail);
                    newEmails.setSubject(inputSubject);
                    newEmails.setBody(inputBody);
                    emailsArrayList.add(newEmails);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    getIntent().putExtra("inputEmail", inputEmail);
                    getIntent().putExtra("inputSubject", inputSubject);
                    getIntent().putExtra("inputBody", inputBody);

                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                    finish();
                }


            }
        });
    }




}
```

Comment: Please post your Emails Class.

Answer (score 0):

I would also change the following as well:

```
private void updateList()
{
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        Emails a = new Emails(intent.getStringExtra("inputEmail"), intent.getStringExtra("inputBody"), intent.getStringExtra("inputSubject"));
        emailAdapter.add(a);
        emailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

to

```
    private void updateList()
    {
Intent intent = getIntent();        
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(bundle != null)
        {
        Emails a = new Emails(String)bundle.get("inputEmail"), (String)bundle.get("inputBody"), (String)bundle.get("inputSubject"));
            emailAdapter.add(a);
            emailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

**I would try this absolutley first:**  You may beable to use what you have and just change the Bundle bundle and Intent intent lines around in your **updateList()**.  Again no expert but try that first and then above that second.  I hope it works for you.